# How to get checkBox  object from c# Xtragrid column

Tags: c#, checkbox, devexpress, xtragrid

Hi all,
   I'm using DevExpress XtraGrid control in a C#.Net application. I'mbinding the values from one table to a grid, and the table contains one bit field: `Authorized`. So the grid displays that column with a checkBox. I want to get that checkBox object or get the event of that control.

[image]

Comment: What event are you looking?  A data changed event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the gridView.ActiveEditor property to get a reference of the currently open editor.  It is available within the CellValueChanged event handler.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using the CellValueChanged or CellValueChanging events tied to the view?  You can use the IDE's property list to wire it up and inside the event use the event args to decide which column you wish to act upon.

Comment: in CellValueChanged  not getting that checkbox object.

Comment: But isn't the value changing the same as the checkbox being checked or not?  I would argue it is the same, the checkbox is just a visual representation of 1 or 0.  A down vote would be acceptable if I offered you my answer but you gave more reason for needing an entire checkbox object other than to test a value change via the checked property.

Comment: CheckBox event not occuring while CellValueChanged .But getting in Itemarray object of selected row.I meant that checkBox control to be get